# how to call an object

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to execute the following code but it is giving me an error

```
  File "/home/utente/Desktop/python/untitled3.py", line 29, in <module>
    bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

```py
    import numpy as np
    
    #import pandas as pd
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    #import matplotlib.lines as lines
    import random as randn
    
    from numpy import r_
    from numpy import sin
    from numpy import pi
    
    
    fs = 44100  # sampling rate
    baud = 300  # symbol rate
    Nbits = 10  # number of bits
    Ns = fs/baud
    N = Nbits * Ns
    f0 = 1800
    # bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0
    
    np.random.seed(seed=1)
    bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0
    M = np.tile(bits,(1,Ns))
    t = r_[0.0:N]/fs
    OOK = M.ravel()*sin(2*pi*f0*t)
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,4))
    plt(t,OOK)
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `fig(t, OOK)`? The error message is telling you you're attempting to call the `plt` _module_ as a function (which you have imported, and then used to greate your figure with `plt.figure`).

Comment: Just *read* the error message. You've imported a module, and you're trying to call it as if it was a function. What is `bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0` supposed to do?

Comment: I am pasting the error statement here                                                                                      File "/home/utente/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 1260, in tile
    return c.reshape(shape_out)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a namespace collision by importing the `random` module as `randn` which is the method you wish to call from that module. So you need to remove that assignment and reference the `np.random.randn` module explicitly (or add a `from np.random import randn`).

```
import numpy as np

#import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.lines as lines
import random as randn                <- REMOVE THIS LINE

from numpy import r_
from numpy import sin
from numpy import pi


fs = 44100  # sampling rate
baud = 300  # symbol rate
Nbits = 10  # number of bits
Ns = fs/baud
N = Nbits * Ns
f0 = 1800
# bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0

np.random.seed(seed=1)
bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0           <- CHANGE THIS TO bits = np.random.randn(Nbits,1) > 0
M = np.tile(bits,(1,Ns))
t = r_[0.0:N]/fs
OOK = M.ravel()*sin(2*pi*f0*t)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,4))
plt(t,OOK)
```

Comment: after doing this which you suggested now it is giving me this erro "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: The error message is clear enough. You're trying to treat an integer variable as a float point number and that is not allowed. I suggest you open the file in the debugger, set a break point on the line that's throwing the error, when the breakpoint hits, examine the types and values of all the variables to determine where the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to call the randn method, it is part of the random module.
Since you imported the random module as randn, the call should be randn.randn(Nbits, 1).

I would suggest usind randn directly from the numpy module, as `np.random.randn(Nbits, 1)`

Comment: after doing this which you suggested now it is giving me this erro "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: In which line? You are probably calling a method with a float type, which it should be an integer.

Comment: I am pasting the error statement here                                                                                      File "/home/utente/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 1260, in tile
    return c.reshape(shape_out)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: The problem is that `np.tile` accepts an integer as the number of repetitions (in your case `Ns`). 
And although `Ns` is an integer, as a result of a division without remainders, its type is a float.

So if you convert `Ns` to an `int` type, it will get the job done:
`M = np.tile(bits,(1,int(Ns)))`

Comment: And I also noted that the last line of your code won't run, for the same module call issue. You need to call `plt.plot(t,OOK)` instead of "calling the module" directly.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions., (I am new in python) after editing my code as you suggested it giving me the following error                                                                                                           File "/home/utente/Desktop/python/testo1.py", line 33, in <module>
    M = np.title(bits,(1,int(Ns)))

  File "/home/utente/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'title'

Comment: You misplaced `np.tile` by `np.title`! 
`M = np.tile(bits,(1,int(Ns)))`

Answer (score 1):

Let's read the error. `'module' object is not callable` in the code `bits = randn(Nbits,1) > 0`.
There is only one function call there, which is `randn()`. However, you imported it as `import random as randn`. This only gives an alias to the module 'random'. What you need to do is use a function from the module, like `random.randint()` (after importing the module 'random', without an alias).

From your code, I assume you are looking for [numpy.random.randn](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html). In that case, add this line to your import statements.

```
from numpy.random import randn
```